# How to mock Constructor in mockito 5.2.0

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito, mockito-inline

I'm upgrading PowerMockito to Mockito 5.2.0, While upgrading, I am facing an issue with mocking the constructor. I have tried many ways to mock the constructor, Can someone let me know how we can convert this to Mockito?

```
Dog dog = PowerMockito.mock(Dog.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(Dog.class)
    .withArguments(ArgumentMatchers.any(cat.class))
    .thenReturn(dog);
```

I have also tried with this :

```
try (MockedConstruction<Fruit> mock = mockConstruction(Fruit.class, withSettings().defaultAnswer(Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS))) {}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary that you stub the constructor? Usually it's a sign of code that is not designed for good testability. Is the stuff that's happening in the constructor so expensive?
If you don't find a way around, you can find the [docs for Mockito](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.8.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#49), #49, but be aware that you have to enable the inline mock maker (see also the docs for that)

Comment: Can you give an example how can i do that - @cyberbrain

Comment: before Mockito 5.0.0, according to the [docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.8.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) you have to "create in the classpath a file /mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker containing the value mock-maker-inline." Starting with Mockito 5.0.0, inline mock maker is enabled by default. (Sorry, I overread that before.)

Comment: I have also followed same documentation but its not working i'm getting NullPointerException @cyberbrain

Comment: Please add this information and the NPE with stacktrace to your question - it's important to know what you already have tried and what didn't work.